# Script in HTML to handle returned message from Bottle

Tags: javascript, python, html, bottle

I am writing a small script in Bottle that reads user input from the HTML via POST. I would like to send the result back to the HTML from the Bottle function that could be analyzed by a script in the HTML.

Bottle Code:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return template("user_info.tpl", message = "please enter your data: ")
@app.route("/", method="POST")
def formhandler():

    x = int(request.forms.get('x'))
    y = int(request.forms.get('y'))
    piece = request.forms.get("value")
    final_output = int(slope)*int(value) + int(intercept)
    return template("user_info.tpl", message=str(final_output))
app.run(host="localhost", port = 8080, debug = True)
```

My HTML so far:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Form Example</title>

 </head>
 <body>
   <form method="post" action="/">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>SAMPLE FORM</legend>
    <ul>
      <li>Enter the row: <input name='x'>
      </li>
      <li>Enter the column: <input name='y'>
      </li>
      <li>Enter the piece name: <input name ="name">
      </li>
    </ul><input type='submit' value='Submit Form'>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<p>Quantitity: {{message}}</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (message >= 100)
{
  window.alert("Too high");
}
else {

  window.alert("Just perfect");
}

</script>
```

At the bottle of my HTML file, I am attempting to run a very simple script to analyze the returned value. However, no popup is triggered, even though I enter values that match the control condition. How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to give the javascript if condition like `if ({{message}} >= 100)` only then you will get the variable there, if you want you can go to the console and check the script for the value present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few possible problems:

1. `request.forms.get("value")` -- you don't have value field on the form
2. `final_output = int(slope)*int(value) + int(intercept)` -- no mentions of `slope` and `intercept` in the code
3. you don't have `message` variable in JS, so add `var message = {{message}}` to the section

Comment: Thank you very much! You pointed out the exact flaws. It works now.